# Cannot delete the first node from Linked List class

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have an issue. I'm using the Cracking the Coding Interview textbook to practice some interview questions on Linked Lists, and I attempted to implement my own LinkedList data structure, before solving a problem. I was trying to test the functionality of the class. Everything else works great, but I cannot figure out how to delete the first node of a LinkedList.

After figuring out that my own implementation, of the code doesn't work, I tried the code from the CTCI book, to no avail. Below is my Linked List Data structure code:

```
static class Node{
        Node next = null;
        int data;

        public Node(int d) {
            data = d;
        }

        void appendToTail(int d) {
            Node end = new Node(d);
            Node n = this;
            while(n.next != null) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            n.next = end;
        }

        Node deleteNode(Node head, int d) {
            if(head == null) return null;
            Node n = head;
            if(n.data == d) {
                return head.next;
            }

            while(n.next != null) {
                if(n.next.data == d) {
                    n.next = n.next.next;
                    return head;
                }
                n = n.next;
            }
            return head;

        }

        int size () {
            int length = 0;
            Node n = this;
            if(n == null) {
                return 0;
            } 
            length = 1;
            while(n.next != null) {
                n = n.next;
                length++;
            }

            return length;
        }

        void printNode() {
            Node d = this;
            while(d != null) {
                if(d.next != null) {
                    System.out.print(d.data + " --> ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(d.data + " ");
                }

                d = d.next;
            }
        }

    }
```

I was wondering why I was able to delete every other node except the first one.

I did set the following test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test cases
        Node test = new Node(0);
        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            test.appendToTail(i);
        }

        test.printNode();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i = i + 2) {
            test.deleteNode(test, i);
        }

        test.printNode();


    }
```

The output I received after deleting all the even nodes is `0 --> 1 --> 3 --> 5 --> 7 --> 9 --> 11 --> 13 --> 15 --> 17 --> 19` but my expected output is `1 --> 3 --> 5 --> 7 --> 9 --> 11 --> 13 --> 15 --> 17 --> 19` .

Comment: You'll want ```deleteNode()``` to return the first node of the list. If you remove anything but the first node, nothing will change. However, if you remove the first node, it will return the 2nd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, when deleting the first element in linked list you are sending the head.next but you are not consuming it in test variable.

The code should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test cases
        Node test = new Node(0);
        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            test.appendToTail(i);
        }

        test.printNode();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i = i + 2) {
            test = test.deleteNode(test, i);
        }

        test.printNode();


    }
```

add this

```
test = test.deleteNode(test, i);
```

Then the result will be

```
0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> 8 --> 9 --> 10 --> 11 --> 12 --> 13 --> 14 --> 15 --> 16 --> 17 --> 18 --> 19 --> 20
3 --> 5 --> 7 --> 9 --> 11 --> 13 --> 15 --> 17 --> 19
```

Comment: The solution works, though I'm not sure if it increases the complexity of the code to an impractical level, since you have to iterate through the linkedlist n^2 times (n for every element deleted, technically n(n+1)/2 which is still O(n^2)).